# Multiple MassTransit buses

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I am using MassTransit to consume messages (using a Service Bus transport) in a console app.

I am using `services.AddMassTransit(...)` extension method (from MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection 5.3.2) to configure the bus:

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(c =>
{
    c.AddConsumer<MyEventConsumer>();

    c.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
    {
        var options = provider.GetService<IOptions<ServiceBusOptions>>().Value;
        var host = cfg.Host(
            options.ConnectionString,
            sbhc => { });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, options.SubscriptionName, e =>
        {            
            e.ConfigureConsumer<MyEventConsumer>(provider);            
        });        
    }));
});
```

I now need to publish events to a different bus (a different Service Bus connection string).

Am I corrent in thinking that I effectively need to create a second bus by calling `Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus` inside the `services.AddMassTransit(...` block and somehow pass the that instance to the consumer for the first bus?

How do I go about it?

Comment: Well, that's probably the best way to do it. You can add multiple hosts on a single bus, but it isn't very well tested and when you call Publish within a consumer, events are only published to that same host. You might be able to use IBus to publish, if you put the other host first in the configuration. Never tried it though.

Comment: @Muxa why do you even use the container? If the code sample is complete, your consumer is parameterless. You can just avoid using the container and pass dependencies explicitly. You only need a hosted service that will take care of starting and stopping the bus.